# Splitting workbook into multiple files by sheet: how do I get the saved workbook name to be the sheet title?

Tags: excel, vba, file

I am trying to create a macro that splits a given workbook into multiple files that are saved to the same folder with the titles=current sheet names. I currently have it working, but the saved titles come out as "Book67", "Book68", "Book69", etc. and not the sheet title.

Already tried various types of object titles for Worksheet Name (fourth line from the bottom) but to no avail. I that's still where I think the problem is.

```
Sub Splitbook()
MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
sht.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs
Filename = MyPath & "/" & "Worksheet.Name" & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
Next sht
End Sub
```

No error messages. Expected results listed above

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=myPath & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".xlsx"`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick help. I tried your advice,and I get this error, though: "Compile error: Expected: expression"

Comment: Sub Splitbook()
MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
sht.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename =:MyPath & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
Next sht
End Sub

Comment: *Update your question* if you need to add code - code in comments is difficult to read.

Comment: Fair point. I tried his suggestion, but it didn't work. The edited line in question looked like this:                                                                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename =:MyPath & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".xlsx"

Comment: The VBE places your cursor straight on the problem in your error. `Filename =:MyPath` should be `Filename:=MyPath`. More specifically, `:=` instead of `=:`.

Comment: First time using VBA. Thanks for the help everyone!